# Background color change of found text in notepad++

Tags: colors, notepad++, highlighting

when i search a text pattern using "**find all in current document**" option in Find window, how to set the background of the selected result. Like currently i am searching "I" in the complete file, need the search result background to change when i select a particular line.

attaching a snapshot of same.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Settings > Style Configurator
```

Under `Language` find "`Search result`" (on my notepad++ this is the one at the bottom)
Under `style` change as wished